# How to check if an ExecutionResult is empty in Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j

I am executing a query in neo4j using java. I don't know how to check if the execution result is empty. Here is my code.

```
String firstquery=" start n=node(*) match(b)-[relatedto]->(n) where b.value=\""+applicationName+"\" return n";  
    ExecutionResult execResult = execEngine.execute(firstquery);
    System.out.println("executing query");
    String results = execResult.dumpToString();
    System.out.println(results);
    Iterator<Node> n_column1 = execResult.columnAs( "n" );
    System.out.println("n column 1 :"+n_column1);
    if (n_column1 ==null)
    {
        System.out.println("Has no rows");

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("results are there");
    }
```

My `results.dumpToString()` looks like this. I am confused over the condition in the `if` that will check if it has 0 results or not.

```
+---+
| n |
+---+
+---+
0 row
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An execution result is essentially an iterator of a map, its type definition is something like:

```
Iterable<Map<String,Object>>
```

So you can easily just do:

```
result.iterator().hasNext();
```

I think that its strictly a ResourceIterator, so if you get an iterator you are supposed to close it if you don't exhaust it. Check the neo4j documentation for ResourceIterator.

Comment: I did an execResult.iterator.hasNext() . But still it is showing as results are there @Luanne

Comment: hasNext is a boolean. I was suggesting you use if(execResult.iterator().hasNext()) for your print statement.